# Python doesn't save file with unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

Python doesn't save the file with Hebrew characters. How do I fix this? (Python 2.7)

[image]

The example image shows a file in the SPE IDE with a first line of

```
heb = ["ד" ,"ג" ,"ב", "א", ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line at the top of your file to specify the encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

[PEP 0263 - Defining Python Source Code Encodings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Comment: thanks! solved that for me @Ashwini Chaudhary

Comment: @downvoter care to explain your downvote?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Not me, have an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

The editor is trying to save in an encoding that doesn't support the characters you use.
Specifying the encoding in the file, with

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

And tell SPE to save in UT-F8 (in the settings somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether the problem is with your IDE or Python.

To get Python to behave properly, you need to [declare the source file encoding](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) in the source.